# Is there a way to resolve an RDS endpoint from an ec2 instance both in the same private subnet, without using a NAT gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

For context, I have a RDS instance and a server both in the same private subnet. Routing rules and security groups are configured to allow the connection.

Connecting from the server to the RDS instance works but only if I have a NAT gateway configured. My guess is this is being caused by a failed DNS resolution that uses the internet.

Is there a way to connect directly via private ip? Or maybe resolve the endpoint without needing to attach a NAT in the routing table?

Comment: Instead of guessing that DNS resolution is the problem, try something like `ping` or `nslookup` on the EC2 instance to see if the DNS actually resolves to an IP or not. If DNS is actually the problem, then you need to check if `enableDnsSupport` and `enableDnsHostnames` settings are enabled on your VPC. Also, verify that you don't have `pubiclyAccessible` enabled on your RDS server.

Comment: Please show us how you have configured the Security Group on the RDS instance. Also, what is the setting of the `Publicly Available` setting on the RDS database?

Answer (score 1):

The **security groups** should be configured as follows:

- A security group on the EC2-instance (`App-SG`) that permits desired Inbound access, plus default Outbound "Allow All" permission
- A security group on the Amazon RDS database (`RDS-SG`) that permits Inbound access on the desired port (eg 3306) **from the `App-SG`**

That is, `RDS-SG` should specifically reference `App-SG` in the Inbound rule. This permits inbound access from any EC2 instance that is associated with the `App-SG` security group. This is much better than referring to IP addresses.

Then, your application should reference the RDS database using its DNS name. This will be resolved to a **private IP address**.